# Max of two vectors - how is this evaluated?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $\max \{\mathbb{v},0\}$ where $\mathbb{v}$ is some vector. When the elements of a vector are all positive or all negative, this is obvious, but what occurs if there are some positive elements and some negative elements?

Comment: It's exactly as you say. You can't make a choice without a reasonable definition of order. One way is to choose the vector with the larger norm, but this doesn't give a unique maximum.

Comment: It depends entirely on how you define $\max$.  It is perfectly reasonable to define $\max \{\mathbb{v},0\}$ as being *vector valued*.  In that case there is no ambiguity.  For example, if $v = [-1, 1]^T$ then $\max \{\mathbb{v},0\} = [0, 1]^T$

Comment: Yep, it depends on your definition. In MATLAB, for instance, `max(v,0)` returns a vector where the elements are $v_i$ if $v_i\geq 0$, and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

if you use the norm always max will be $v$ because norm is always positive.

for example you can find max from compare of sum of coordinate:
$v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$

$$\max\{v,0\}= \max\{v_1+\cdots+v_n,0\}$$